# Image styled with max-width in % is output in px by Firefox. Works in Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, fluid-layout

It is hard to give this problem a simple title but I hope someone can help me.. Please have a look at this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mrmartineau/AaeJY/ - in both Firefox & Chrome. The  image is styled with a `max-width: 80%` which should make it fluid but I have found a bug in Firefox which registers the max-width value in pixels rather than the, correct, percentage.

Now, I  discovered this while trying the get the max-width value using jQuery: `$('img').css('maxWidth');`

Is this a bug or the correct result? Is there something else that I can do to get the real max-width value using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I think this all depends on how the jQuery looks for the max-width property.

If you use the `getComputedStyle` in Javascript it should return you a value of pixels, with the exception of a [bug in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44266) and [IE using a different Javascript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536497.aspx) call altogether. In other words, getting pixels is the expected result.

If you're looking to get the result after it changes try wrapping that call in an `onWindowResize`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, but I would really like to get back the same value (in this case %) as is declared in the CSS. I think your window resize idea is the solution. Cheers man!